# Batch script for copying files by date

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I need batch script to copy all files created on todays date from one directory to another and rename them all to a default name (ex. NAME54.pdf) and continue counting from destination`s maximum number in name.

Comment: What did you try ? There is various example to do that on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that will take a source and destination directory, and copying the files from the source directory to the destination directory, renaming the scripts to NAMES#.pdf.  The files copied will be the files with today's timestamp

```
@echo off
REM setting up variable expansion for later use
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM giving the inputted values easy to read variable names
SET source_dir=%1
SET dest_dir=%2

REM checks to see if the directories exist
if not exist "%source_dir%" (
    set is_failure=true
)
if not exist "%dest_dir%" (
    set is_failure=true
)

REM Instructions given before failure
if "%is_failure%"=="true" (
    echo ERROR: The parameters passed were not directories\n\n
    echo INSTRUCTIONS
    echo.
    echo command syntax:
    echo script.bat 'path to source directory' 'path to destination directory'
    exit /b 1
)

REM finding the NAME#.pdf files, and getting the highest number
SET i=0
for %%x in (%dest_dir%\NAME*.pdf) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  set "FN=!FN:NAME=!"
  if !FN! GTR !i! set i=!FN!
)

REM checking that the file exists
if exist %dest_dir%\NAME%i%.pdf (
    set /A i=i+1
)

REM Iterating over the list of files, and copying them to the new name
REM Only taking the files with today's date
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%A IN ('"dir %source_dir% /OD /A-D "') DO (
    echo %%A | findstr %DATE%>nul && (
        set file_name=%%D
        copy /Y %source_dir%\!file_name! %dest_dir%\NAME!i!.pdf
        set /A i=i+1
    )
)
```

This should accomplish what you need to do